# Why don't my VST instruments have sound in cubase?

Tags: audio, midi, vst, cubase, sound

My VST instruments lost their sound in cubase. I connected two MIDi interfaces that control the Roland TR909 and the Cyclone 303 bass, they work via MIDI but a) My MIDI keyboard makes no sound and b) VST tracks and VST instruments make no sound. To inspect the matter I've recorded a video with the issue that you may inspect [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79COpCaiVUI&feature=youtu.be).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does *any* audio work from Cubase? Your ASIO4ALL window suggests your outputs aren't working, at the driver level.

Comment: @WarriorBob Thank you for the comment. It has started to work intemittently as I'm learning cubase. For some projects it all works, so it's a settings issue for me and multiple cheap MIDI interfaces do in fact work.